# Как посмотреть поднятые Spring bean-ы в сервере приложений (TomCat,WildFly и т.п.)?

Tags: java, spring

Всем добрый день.
К примеру создал я простейшее Spring MVC приложение Hello_world и поднял его в TomCat.
Как я могу посмотреть снаружи какие бины поднялись в TomCat, включая мои спринговые.
Напрашивается JMX и JConsole, но что-то я там спрингового ничего не вижу.

Направьте на пусть истинный..

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat ничего не знает о бинах. Сделайте в своём приложении какую-нибудь страницу или rest-эндпоинт, который будет отдавать эту информацию. Что-нибудь вроде

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/monitoring/beans")
public class BeansController {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getBeanList() {
        return Arrays.asList(appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames());
    }
}
```

Или можно объявить свой MBean, экспортирующий эту же информацию, и получать данные в JConsole.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что о бинах не знает любой ApplicationServer (TomCat,WildFly и т.п.) ?

Comment: О бинах Spring'а знает только сам Spring. Application server'ы, к которым Tomcat не относится, могут знать про enterprise java bean'ы.